# Wordpress: get_term() offset parameter not working

Tags: php, wordpress, offset, categories, custom-taxonomy

I don't understand why the offset parameter for get_terms isn't working. This should start from the 5th iteration excluding the 1st to 4th but still it display all the taxonomies on my end.

Here's my code:

```
  $countterms = wp_count_terms( 'item_category' );
  $offset = 4;
  $number = $countterms - $offset;
  $terms = get_terms( 'item_category', array(
      'hide_empty' => true,
      'orderby'    => 'name', 
      'order'      => 'ASC',
      'exclude'    => array(145,138,110,139,140,141,130,142,144,116,143),
      'offset'     => $offset,
      'number'     => $number
  ) );
```

Any suggestion to my problem would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: Do you find any error in the console or the debug log file?

Answer (score 0):

Here you need also to apply your exclude terms in `wp_count_terms()` function:

```
$exclude = array(145,138,110,139,140,141,130,142,144,116,143)
$countterms = wp_count_terms( 'item_category', array(
    // 'hide_empty' => true, // optional (see if you need it)
    'exclude' => $exclude
) );
$offset = 4;
$number = $countterms - $offset;
$terms = get_terms( 'item_category', array(
    'hide_empty' => true,
    'orderby'    => 'name', 
    'order'      => 'ASC',
    'exclude'    => $exclude,
    'offset'     => $offset,
    'number'     => $number
) );
```

`wp_count_terms()` function works as `get_terms()`, so you can apply to it your excluded terms too.

If not, you get all list like explained in first reference below.

References:

- [get_terms offset working? [SOLVED]](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/get_terms-offset-working?)
- [get_terms() codex - function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/)
- [wp_count_terms() codex - function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_count_terms)